# How to limit TextChangedEvent to user input?

Tags: wpf, textchanged

My issue is simple enough. I have a TextBox which is bound to a viewModel. I want both the viewModel and the user to be able to update the text, so it is a two way binding.

However, if the user updates the text, the colour(Red) should change to indicate a user change. If the text is changed programatically from the viewModel the text should stay the same colour(black).

I've tried using the TextChangedEvent to do this, but the text colour changed regardless of the source of the change. How can I limit the event to just user input?

XAML:

```
<TabItem.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:HeightsTabViewModel/>
</TabItem.DataContext>

<TextBox Text="{Binding TextOutput}"

            PreviewTextInput="TextFilterEvent"
            FontSize="{StaticResource TextBoxFontSize}"
            Margin="{StaticResource UniversalMargin}"

            TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"

        </TextBox>
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if((sender as TextBox).IsLoaded)
        {
            (sender as TextBox).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The only way the binding can update the viewmodel's property is via the property setter. However, the viewmodel can do anything it likes. For example: give the viewmodel a method which sets the private backing field, calls `OnPropertyChanged("TextOutput")`, but does not enter the setter for `TextOutput`. Add a public boolean property, `IsTextOutputUserUpdated` or something. The `TextOutput` setter sets `IsTextOutputUserUpdated = true;`. The update method sets `IsTextOutputUserUpdated = false;`.

Comment: Then use a value converter or a style trigger to set the TextBox's foreground color based on `IsTextOutputUserUpdated`. Don't do that in code behind.